# Change prefix in XML SOAP

Tags: xml, soap, prefix

I try to change my prefix from "SOAP-ENV" to "s", but I cannot handler. I use PHP. I will be very grateful in someone help me. Thanks in advance.

My XML:

```
<SOAP-ENV:Envelope xmlns:SOAP-ENV="http://schemas.xmlso.......
```

I want to be:

```
<s:Envelope xmlns:s="http://schemas.xmlso.......
```

Comment: it seems that you did not finish you question

Comment: I'm wondering why you need to bother changing the xml -- you can use an alternative prefix with the parsers, xsl, xpath, etc.  All that matters is the namespace URI matches for the prefixes you have choosen to use.